# Manipulating a public UI object from another class

Tags: oop, qt

I have a main window class built in Qt Designer and called `Ui_MainWindow` which has a publicly defined `QProgressBar` object called `*downloadProgressBar`. I also have a class called `HttpGet`, which is supposed to download a file from a url supplied by the user. There is a function called `HttpGet :: updateReadProgress` that is intended to update `downloadProgressBar` as the file is downloaded, which would require manipulation of the progress bar from within the function, but I unable to figure out how to go about this.

My assumption would be that I would include the relevant header file and then access the progress bar object via

```
Ui_MainWindow :: downloadProgressBar -> setValue()
```

but when I try to compile this code, I get the following error:

```
error: ‘downloadProgressBar’ is not a member of ‘Ui_MainWindow’
```

which tells me that I've misunderstood what it is I'm asking the compiler to do. Can someone please tell me how I should go about updating the progress bar from within `HttpGet`, or if that's the wrong thing to do, can you please give me a better alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ui_MainWindow` is a class. you need object of that class to deal with members.
Also, you should read [C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4 (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160) before writing more code. it's awailable in pdf around the web...